# cbind function creates misaligned xts object

Tags: r, xts, cbind

I am trying to run the code in a tutorial by rbresearch titled '[Low Volatility with R](http://rbresearch.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/low-volatility-with-r/)', however when trying to run the `cbind` function the time series seems to get totally misaligned.

**Here's the data-preparation section that works perfectly:**

```
require(quantmod)

symbols = c("XLY", "XLP", "XLE", "XLF", "XLV", "XLI", "XLK", "XLB", "XLU")
getSymbols(symbols, index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"), from='2000-01-01')

for(symbol in symbols) {
  x<-get(symbol)
  x<-to.monthly(x,indexAt='lastof',drop.time=TRUE)
  indexFormat(x)<-'%Y-%m-%d'
  colnames(x)<-gsub("x",symbol,colnames(x))
  assign(symbol,x)
}

for(symbol in symbols) {
  x <- get(symbol)
  x1 <- ROC(Ad(x), n=1, type="continuous", na.pad=TRUE)
  colnames(x1) <- "ROC"
  colnames(x1) <- paste("x",colnames(x1), sep =".")
  #x2 is the 12 period standard deviation of the 1 month return
  x2 <- runSD(x1, n=12)
  colnames(x2) <- "RANK"
  colnames(x2) <- paste("x",colnames(x2), sep =".")
  x <- cbind(x,x2)
  colnames(x)<-gsub("x",symbol,colnames(x))
  assign(symbol,x)
}

rank.factors <- cbind(XLB$XLB.RANK, XLE$XLE.RANK, XLF$XLF.RANK, XLI$XLI.RANK,
  XLK$XLK.RANK, XLP$XLP.RANK, XLU$XLU.RANK, XLV$XLV.RANK, XLY$XLY.RANK)

r <- as.xts(t(apply(rank.factors, 1, rank)))

for (symbol in symbols){
  x <- get(symbol)
  x <- x[,1:6]
  assign(symbol,x)
}
```

**To illustrate that the XLE ETF data data is aligned with the XLE Ranked data:**

```
> head(XLE)
            XLE.Open XLE.High XLE.Low XLE.Close XLE.Vodalume XLE.Adjusted
 2000-01-31    27.31    29.47   25.87     27.31    5903600        22.46
 2000-02-29    27.31    27.61   24.62     26.16    4213000        21.51
 2000-03-31    26.02    30.22   25.94     29.31    8607600        24.10
 2000-04-30    29.50    30.16   27.52     28.87    5818900        23.74
 2000-05-31    29.19    32.31   29.00     32.27    5148800        26.54
 2000-06-30    32.16    32.50   30.09     30.34    4563100        25.07
> nrow(XLE)
[1] 163
> head(r$XLE.RANK)
            XLE.RANK
 2000-01-31        2
 2000-02-29        2
 2000-03-31        2
 2000-04-30        2
 2000-05-31        2
 2000-06-30        2
nrow(r$XLE.RANK)
[1] 163
```

**However after running the following `cbind` function, the xts object becomes totally misaligned:**

```
> XLE <- cbind(XLE, r$XLE.RANK)
> head(XLE)
           XLE.Open XLE.High XLE.Low XLE.Close XLE.Volume XLE.Adjusted XLE.RANK
2000-01-31    27.31    29.47   25.87     27.31    5903600        22.46       NA
2000-01-31       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA        2
2000-02-29    27.31    27.61   24.62     26.16    4213000        21.51       NA
2000-02-29       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA        2
2000-03-31    26.02    30.22   25.94     29.31    8607600        24.10       NA
2000-03-31       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA        2
> nrow(XLE)
[1] 326
```

Since running pre-existing code seldom works for me, I suspect there's something wrong with my R console, so here's my session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] timeSeries_3010.97         timeDate_3010.98           quantstrat_0.7.8           foreach_1.4.1             
 [5] blotter_0.8.14             PerformanceAnalytics_1.1.0 FinancialInstrument_1.1.9  quantmod_0.4-0            
 [9] Defaults_1.1-1             TTR_0.22-0                 xts_0.9-5                  zoo_1.7-10                

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 grid_3.0.1      iterators_1.0.6 lattice_0.20-15 tools_3.0.1
```

I'm completely unsure how to properly align the xts object without the `NA` and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Works fine for me (although _holy cow_ was installing `quantstrat` an involved process). All I can think of is that somehow you have a strange `cbind` method floating around that's being called by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that! A buddy of mine ran it and it worked perfectly for him as well. I decided to uninstall and re-install R, install the quantstrat package only to face the same exact error. Almost none of the code that is uploaded online works for me. I am convinced something is wrong with either the R software or my new laptop.

Comment: try `XLE$XLE.RANK <- an.numeric(r$XLE.RANK)`

Comment: That didn't work. I also tried using an older version of R, 2.15 but that didn't help either.

Comment: There has been some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706335/upgraded-quantstrat-0-7-8-from-0-7-7-then-old-code-does-not-work) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120496/guy-yollins-quantstrat-i-lecture-issue) about problems with older quanstrat examples, due to code being updated pretty rapidly. May want to see if either apply to your situation.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with quantstrat because the question doesn't run any quantstrat code except for `stock` and `currency`, which aren't necessary. I don't understand how the `cbind` call could be working for anyone though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how anyone was not able to replicate your issue.  The problem is this line:

```
r <- as.xts(t(apply(rank.factors, 1, rank)))
```

The first for loop converts the data to monthly and drops the time component of the index, which converts the index to a `Date`.  This means that `rank.factors` has a `Date` index.  But `as.xts` creates a `POSIXct` index by default, so `r` will have a `POSIXct` index.

`cbind(XLE, r$XLE.RANK)` is merging an xts object with a `Date` index with an xts object with a `POSIXct` index.  The conversion from `POSIXct` to `Date` can be problematic if you're not very careful with timezone settings.

If you don't need the time component, it's best to avoid `POSIXct` and just use `Date`.  Therefore, everything should work if you set `dateFormat="Date"` in your `as.xts` call.

```
R> r <- as.xts(t(apply(rank.factors, 1, rank)), dateFormat="Date")
R> XLE <- cbind(XLE, r$XLE.RANK)
R> head(XLE)
           XLE.Open XLE.High XLE.Low XLE.Close XLE.Volume XLE.Adjusted XLE.RANK
2000-01-31    27.31    29.47   25.87     27.31    5903600        22.46        2
2000-02-29    27.31    27.61   24.62     26.16    4213000        21.51        2
2000-03-31    26.02    30.22   25.94     29.31    8607600        24.10        2
2000-04-30    29.50    30.16   27.52     28.87    5818900        23.74        2
2000-05-31    29.19    32.31   29.00     32.27    5148800        26.54        2
2000-06-30    32.16    32.50   30.09     30.34    4563100        25.07        2
```

Comment: Thanks so much Josh, that resolved the issue. I must admit, I was just about to reformat my laptop and in the likely event that it did not resolve the issue, I would have lost all hope in using R.